# How to modify labels when augmenting data using keras

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, keras

I am working on a regression nn.
I am using keras 1.2.1, and want to use data augmentation to improve my model.
I have modified my code to use a generator for this purpose:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True)
datagen.fit(X_train, y_train, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.2, nb_epoch=EPOCHS, callbacks=callbacks)
```

The piece that I am stuck on is that I need to modify the the associated y_label for this data to account for the fact that I flipped the image horizontally.
In this simple example, I essentially need to flip the sign of y_label from positive to negative, and vice versa, *IF* the image was flipped.

Comment: If you change the labels then its not the typical data augmentation, and you would have to make a custom generator that does what you want.

Comment: Isn't it just create a function (not a keras model) that makes `newX = flip(X_train)` and `newY = -y_train`??

Comment: Why not modify your training data set to include both the unflipped and flipped data with suitably modified y_labels?  This would remove the need to explicitly change the label during training.  Only drawback is that it will effectively double the size of you training data set...

Answer (score 1):

In the recent tensorflow-keras versions, we can do it within a **map** data augmentation function, using tf.data API.

```
   flip_prob=tf.random.uniform(shape=[1])

   image = tf.cond(flip_prob < 0.5, lambda: tf.image.flip_left_right(image), lambda: image)
   label = tf.cond(flip_prob < 0.5, lambda: -label, lambda: label) # label is int
```

We can also use **tf.py_function** with python conditional statements(for augmentation) to acheive the same results.